# Creating a table with 2 primary keys and two foreign keys referring to 2 different tables with same constraint name

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key

For this particular schema:

[image: This is the schema]

I have created the department student and subject tables now the problem right now arises in the creation of the mark table.

It is specified that there are 2 primary keys and 2 foreign keys , but as the title suggests creating 2 foreign keys referring to 2 different tables having the same constraint name seems impossible as per my understanding by surfing on the internet and reading on few threads here.

Is there any way to do this ? I want to have both the foreign key's constraint name to be "fk".

This code pops with a identifier error:

```
create table mark(
    value number,
    subject_id number,
    student_id number,
    constraint pk primary key(subject_id,student_id),
    constraint fk foreign key(subject_id,student_id) references subject(subject_id,student_id));
```

But even if i create 2 constraints with different name test cases fail. Is there a solution?

This is department table

```
create table department(
    department_id number(2),
    department_name varchar(30),
    department_block_number number,
    constraint PK primary key(department_id));
```

This is student table

```
create table student(
        student_id number,
        student_name varchar(30),
        address varchar(40),
        city varchar(30),
        department_id number,
        constraint pk primary key(student_id),
        constraint fk foreign key(department_id) references department(department_id));
```

This is staff table

```
create table staff(
    staff_id number,
    staff_name varchar(30),
    department_id number,
    constraint pk primary key(staff_id),
    constraint fk foreign key(department_id) references department(department_id));
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not images (by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59901559/edit) your question). It would be helpful to include the `create` statements for the referenced tables too.

Comment: I have edited and added the referenced tables :D

Comment: Thanks; have you created the subject table too? (though you can't have actually created all of those as the constraint names aren't unique...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a composite primary key - on more than one column - which is fine; but you can't have a composite foreign key as the student table doesn't have a `subject_id` column - hence it giving you an invalid-identifier error.

You need *two* foreign keys, something like:

```
create table mark(
    value number,
    subject_id number,
    student_id number,
    constraint mark_pk primary key(subject_id,student_id),
    constraint mark_fk_subject foreign key(subject_id) references subject(subject_id),
    constraint mark_fk_student foreign key(student_id) references student(student_id));
```

The constraint names have to be unique, both within and across tables in the same schema, and something more descriptive than 'pk' or 'fk' would be sensible anyway.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0c3df60753547159a9880b1f31ed11e1)

Comment: hey, new update in the problem now, when i did change the constraints name i get a an error in passing the test cases...  Test case - Column constraint check

Check the constraint(s) for the column(s)

STUDENT_ID
STUDENT_ID
SUBJECT_ID
SUBJECT_ID

Comment: I have no idea how or where you are seeing that. Do you get an ORA- error when you create an object?

Comment: The thing is when i run the code with different constrain names the code runs and throws no error on the editor window but when i try to evaluate the code on the test cases it fails and displays to check the constraints ... 0.0

Comment: Well, the tables can all be created (see [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0c3df60753547159a9880b1f31ed11e1)), and I don't know what your test cases are doing, so can't really comment on those.